# message.content is empty for bot client (pycord)

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have simplest python program of discord bot

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    print(msg.content)

bot.run('token')
```

And it prints just empty string. Before that I tried bot.command() but bot simply doesn't responds to it probably because message is empty so like there's no command. I saw this problem mostly occurs for selfbot clients but in my case client is bot. Would be glad for any help

Comment: and what makes problem? maybe sometimes system sends empty messages - and maybe you should skip them (using `if/else`)

Comment: maybe you should send this to authors as issue: https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Python 3.9, py-cord 2.0.0, Linux Mint 20.3

Comment: pycord needs intents maybe try enabling intents it may start working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the `message` intents on https://discord.com/developers/applications
and need to pass them to your `commands.Bot`

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

would be an example of how you can do that.